# How to deal with local network changes (NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription) on iOS 14?

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios, tcpclient, local-network

Our application connects to a local WiFi network (using TCPClient) for data communication purposes.

But in iOS 14 the connection fails completely because two processes take place at the same time:

1. TCP client initialization
2. Current network permissions

So the connection to the local network is blocked until we reopen the application.

To avoid this, we're doing a hack: Pinging to a local IP address triggers the current network permissions (this is done in the OnActivated() method of AppDelegate).

The connection only works properly if it is connected to that particular network otherwise it fails.

Has anyone faced this issue before? I appreciate any suggestions from the community.

Comment: It would be better to send http request when loading the first(root) page instead of in AppDelegate .

Comment: Could you post the relevant code , which will be helpful to solve the issue .